# Signup data not inserting into database in Codeigniter? Redirect not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create a simple signup form but am having trouble adding the data from the form into my database? What am I doing incorrectly that the data won't post to my users table?

Also is simply loading the view again the improper thing to do if the validation fails? Using redirect simply failed and said that I should try clearing my cookies.

My code is below.

**Sign Up Controller:**

```
class Signup extends CI_Controller
{
public function index()
{
  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('signup');
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

function signup_validation() {
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[4]|is_unique[users.username]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|min_length[6]|matches[password]');
  if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    $this->load->model('signup_model');
    redirect('login');
  }
  else {
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('signup');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
}
}
```

**Sign Up Model:**

```
class Signup_model extends CI_Model {
public function index()
{
  $url = url_title($this->input->post('user'), 'dash', true);

  $data = array(
    'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
    'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'password' => $this->input->post('password')
  );

  return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}
}
```

**Sign Up View:**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('signup/signup_validation') ?>" method="POST">

 <h5>First Name</h5>
 <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" />
 <span><?php echo form_error('first_name'); ?></span>

 <h5>Last Name</h5>
 <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" />
 <span><?php echo form_error('last_name'); ?></span>

 <h5>Username</h5>
 <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
 <span><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></span>

 <h5>Email Address</h5>
 <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
 <span><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>

 <h5>Password</h5>
 <input type="text" name="password" value="" />
 <span><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>

 <h5>Password Confirm</h5>
 <input type="text" name="passconf" value="" />
 <span><?php echo form_error('passconf'); ?></span>

 <div><input type="submit" value="Register" /></div>

</form>
```

Comment: You have called the model but not the function under where you load the model try add `$this->signup_model->index();` also https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have loaded a the model but not the function

The [loading of a model guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model)

```
function signup_validation() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[4]|is_unique[users.username]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|min_length[6]|matches[password]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->load->model('signup_model');

        $this->signup_model->index();
        redirect('login');

    } else {

      $this->load->view('templates/header');
      $this->load->view('signup');
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

  }

}
```